# Как правильно и в чём разница между двумя вариантами окончания слова в предложении?

Tags: окончания, выбор-варианта

"Неевклидово пространство"
или
"Неевклидовое пространство".

Как правильно, в чём разница, и есть ли у этого какое-то общее правило?